# Sending mail using FluentEmail

Tags: c#, email

I made a random Gmail account.I want that account to send to my personal Gmail account something, using C#. I found out about FluentEmail these days. This is the class:

```
public static class EmailSender
    {
        //the random account mail and password
        private static  string username = "blabla";
        private static  string password = "blabla";
        
         static EmailSender()
        {
            
            NetworkCredential myCredentials = new NetworkCredential();
            myCredentials.UserName = username;
            myCredentials.Password = password;
            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                Credentials = myCredentials,
                Port = 465,
                EnableSsl = true,
                

            };
            var sender = new SmtpSender(() => smtp);
            Email.DefaultSender = sender;
        }
        public static async Task SendEmail(string body)
        { 
            var email = await Email
                .From(username)
                .To("mymail")
                .Subject("NEW BUG")
                .Body(body)
                .SendAsync();
            if (email.Successful)
            {
                Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("Your message was sent!", "Succesful", "Ok");
            }
        
        }

    }
```

I don't know why but nothing happens when I click the send button.When I click it 2 times in a row the app crashes. I put a breakpoint at the start of the SendEmail function but I still don't know what's wrong. Maybe I set something wrong in the constructor?Thanks.

Comment: And which code does your button run?

Comment: When you are asking a question about an app crashing it is important to include any exception/error information. Check what error messages you get and include them in the description.

Comment: @montonero The sendemail task

Comment: @YungDeiza apparently it crashed because I was clicking send too many times .I added a try catch and now it tells me another async operation is in progress.Which means the sendasync() didn't even finish?How long is it gonna take lol

Comment: That other async operation might also be the message box. If I remember my Xamarin correctly, you also have to await those Acr dialog boxes.

Comment: @youngcoder126 I suggest you add a boolean variable to keep track of whether an attempt to send an email is in progress and prevent further attempts to send an email until the current one has finished.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with FluentEmail, but there are two points which are obviously problematic:

1. You check whether the mail has been sent successfully (`if (email.Successful)`). If it didn't, you just... do nothing. Instead, find out **why** the mail has not been sent and display that information instead. If your return object has a property `Successful`, I'm pretty sure it also has a property telling you what went wrong.
2. I did glimpse at the FluentEmail source code (based on your question), and it apparently uses .NET's built-in `SmtpClient` class. `SmtpClient` does not support SMTPS at port 465. The supported options are unauthenticated SMTP at port 25 or STARTTLS at port 587.

Comment: I added an else statement to that if, which will display email.errormessages.However, it just crashes,says my app is not responding..Idk what ports are/how they're used, I just saw that gmail uses port 465 for SSL here : https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en#zippy=%2Cstep-change-smtp-other-settings-in-your-email-client

Comment: @youngcoder126: That link says that STARTTLS (that's also a kind of SSL) on port 587 is also supported, I suggest to try that instead.